# What's the advantages of using file system to organize our codes

Tags: code-organization, project-organization

It is 2017, and as far as I know, the way programmers organize their codes have not changed. We distribute our codes into files and organize them with a tree structure (nested directories and files). When codebase is huge, and the relations between classes/components are complex, this organization approach gives me the inefficient impression. With more files, either one directory has more files in it or the depth of directories increases. And since we handle the directories directly, navigation costs me time and effort without tools like search.

[image: A complex UML] *Figure: A complex UML from https://github.com/CMPUT301W15T09/Team9Project/wiki/UML*

We can use CAD to design/draw complex things; mind map can be created in a similar manner. For these, we do not need to deal with file systems. Can't we have something similar and hide file system in a black box? Why the fundamental organization methods have not evolved for so long a time.

So I wonder, what's the advantages that keeps us from getting a new way? What's the inherit advantages of using file system to organize our codes.

Comment: "what's the advantages that keeps us from getting a new way" - do you have an example of a new way? If not, question is pointless

Comment: The best I can think of is something like mind map/UML software, we can design the program in a visualized way (canvas). But additionally, class, methods can be visualized and edit individually directly inside the canvas. We do not need to organize the codes into files.

Comment: "this organization approach gives me the messy and inefficient impression." - this is a subjective premise, and a false one at that (in my own subjective experience)

Answer (score 1):

Different on-disk representations of source-code have been tried (e.g. how Flash stores ActionScript inside binary `.fla` files) and they're generally unpopular. No-one likes proprietary file formats. It also means you can't use text-based source control systems like Git, which means you can't do a text-merge to resolve change conflicts.

We store source code in files in a tree structure (e.g. one OOP class or procedural module per file), with nested namespaces represented by nested directories because it's intuitive (and again, for better cohesion with source-control systems).

Some languages enforce this, like Java, for example, that requires the source file be named the same as the class it contains and be in the same directory name as its containing package. For other languages like C# and C++ it just makes sense - because otherwise it's confusing to someone who might be new to your codebase when they see `class TurboEncabulator` inside a file named  `PrefabulatedAmulite.cs`.

Comment: First thank you for answering my question. 
I agree a open format is more popular. 
As for source code control, codes are always text-based, the organization however, does not necessarily break the convenience of Git. File system (even in good convention) is good at handling relations like tree, eg. Namespace, sub-namespace. But when it comes to relations with loops/cycles, it cannot handle it well: I can not easily observe the relationship between two classes in two different directories just by looking at directory structure.